# How to read column of Nan from csvfile into python so data can be used?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, hex, nan

I am trying to read in columns of data from a csvfile, then use it to do some calculations. The problem is that my timestamps are in hexadecimal. I need to read them in and convert to decimal, but I don't know how to get it into python as anything but Nan.

I have tried making it a string first.

```
colnames = [ 'sensor', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'azimuth', 'elevation', 'roll', 'timestamp']

data = pd.read_csv('The Project- 7-19 SS Arc Test.csv', names = colnames)

hexa_time_initial = data.timestamp.tolist()
```

It needs to be a list of hexadecimal, but is just a list of nan. When it tries to run the conversion loop I get the error that it can't convert non-string with explicit base.

[Sample of excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tbWQ.png)

`1,   0.614,  -7.798,  -1.465,  -6.117,   3.050,   5.231,0x42ef4,
  1,   0.615,  -7.798,  -1.465,  -6.109,   3.049,   5.231,0x42f05,
  1,   0.616,  -7.798,  -1.465,  -6.097,   3.045,   5.232,0x42f15,
  1,   0.615,  -7.798,  -1.465,  -6.108,   3.048,   5.232,0x42f26,
  1,   0.614,  -7.798,  -1.465,  -6.121,   3.051,   5.230,0x42f37,
  1,   0.615,  -7.798,  -1.465,  -6.107,   3.048,   5.230,0x42f47,
  1,   0.616,  -7.798,  -1.465,  -6.100,   3.046,   5.230,0x42f58,
  1,   0.614,  -7.798,  -1.465,  -6.116,   3.049,   5.230,0x42f69,`

Comment: Can you add some sample data to question? What is separator in file?

Comment: I added a sample. It's comma separated.

Comment: In my opinion nans means some data related problem. So the best is share data, file (dropbox, gdocs, wetranfer,...) if not confidental.

Comment: The sample isn't visible :( (in case it wasn't clear, we want to see example contents of the csv file - a few actual rows, not your description.)

Comment: @karl I think I successfully added an image of a portion of the file I'm working with

Comment: @Hannah - Unfortuntately from sample it should working nice... So without file not idea...

Comment: @jezrael I guess I'm not sure what you mean by needing the file

Comment: @Hannah - I need your real file for test your code, test if for me are also returned NaNs. And from your picture it is impossible.

Comment: @Hannah you could try, if it works with `dtype={'timestamp': 'str'}`. It should force pandas to store the column values as strings. Then you could perform your transformation in python. Can you open your csv file in an text editor and add them in your description (marked as code)?

Comment: @jottbe I added a sample of the file data (the whole data set is around 1000) in the form of code. Is that what you needed? Also, I tried your idea but no luck.

Comment: @Hannah: I tried your code, it imports it as a string, are the other columns filled in your dataframe? Is it really not stored with ',' or ';' as separator? because the format seems unusual for execel to me. If it really is stored this way, you should be able to import it with `df=pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\s+')` because this is what worked for me. Sep `sep='\s+'` should be safe as long as you have no text columns which contain spaces or tabs. Probably in the file it is tab, so even `sep='\t'` should be sufficient. I don't understand why you gent na.

Comment: @jottbe it is separated by commas. I uploaded a sample from the data I had originally saved at a text file. I didn't realize it would be different from opening an excel file in a text editor. I have two other columns I import using the same method, and I have no issues with them. Is there maybe something I could do to the data pre-import to make it work?

Comment: It seems, it is because of the extra comma at the end. As if pandas get's confused by it. That's probably a bug. You coud remove it before reading and your current code should work, but I wouldn't suggest to do that, because excel's logic which decides how many columns it uses to produce the CSV seems to have a very weird logic, so at times you might also get csv files, that end in several repeated commans, and you don't know beforehand, how many of them you can remove unless you exactly know how many you expect (so it would be possible, but no general solution would apply).

Comment: @jottbe your solution worked perfectly. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I'm glad, I could help-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the example data. I post here, not because I am sure, I found the solution, but because I couldn't show the output in a comment. But I have a suggestion, which might help.

When I read your csv data as you show it in your post, I get the following output:

```
   sensor      x      y      z  azimuth  elevation     roll  timestamp
1   0.614 -7.798 -1.465 -6.117    3.050      5.231  0x42ef4        NaN
1   0.615 -7.798 -1.465 -6.109    3.049      5.231  0x42f05        NaN
1   0.616 -7.798 -1.465 -6.097    3.045      5.232  0x42f15        NaN
1   0.615 -7.798 -1.465 -6.108    3.048      5.232  0x42f26        NaN
1   0.614 -7.798 -1.465 -6.121    3.051      5.230  0x42f37        NaN
1   0.615 -7.798 -1.465 -6.107    3.048      5.230  0x42f47        NaN
1   0.616 -7.798 -1.465 -6.100    3.046      5.230  0x42f58        NaN
1   0.614 -7.798 -1.465 -6.116    3.049      5.230  0x42f69        NaN
```

I recognized, that the `timestamp` column is `NaN`, but also the sensor column is not the first column. I think this is, because the csv line created from excel ends with a comma. Pandas then acts as if there was an (empty) extra column at the end. And because there is one more column as you have names, it seems to create an index with the first column. This then also shifts the column names by one. This behavior seems odd to me, but could also be intended. To be sure, I just created a [bug ticket for this, to be sure](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27515). What pandas version are you using?

If you just change your reading code a bit, you can avoid that:

```
df= pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(raw), sep=',\s*', names=colnames, index_col=False)
```

After reading `df` like this, it looks better:

```
   sensor      x      y      z  azimuth  elevation   roll timestamp
0       1  0.614 -7.798 -1.465   -6.117      3.050  5.231   0x42ef4
1       1  0.615 -7.798 -1.465   -6.109      3.049  5.231   0x42f05
2       1  0.616 -7.798 -1.465   -6.097      3.045  5.232   0x42f15
3       1  0.615 -7.798 -1.465   -6.108      3.048  5.232   0x42f26
4       1  0.614 -7.798 -1.465   -6.121      3.051  5.230   0x42f37
5       1  0.615 -7.798 -1.465   -6.107      3.048  5.230   0x42f47
6       1  0.616 -7.798 -1.465   -6.100      3.046  5.230   0x42f58
7       1  0.614 -7.798 -1.465   -6.116      3.049  5.230   0x42f69
```

Now the column names are assigned correctly. This is because of the `index_col=False` option, which tells pandas not to use the first colum of the file as index.

If you like, you can also add something like `usecols=range(len(colnames))` which tells pandas, that it should only use as many columns from your file as you have names, so if excel runs amok and adds dozens of commas at the end of the lines, you don't get problems because of the many empty and unnamed columns in your dataframes. 
You should check if you really want to use `sep=',\s*'` or rather `sep=','`. The first just makes sure, you remove the leading whitespaces before the values of column 1...